# go api with gin gonic PATCH request not working

Tags: rest, go, go-gin

I am a beginner in go trying to write my first simple API using the gin gonic framework. I have a mock set of data in a struct that holds information about a number of books available in a library.
For some reason when I try and submit a patch request to the API
by either attempting to return a book using the

`curl localhost:8080/return?id=2  --request "PATCH"`

command or attempt to checkout a book using the

`url localhost:8080/checkout?=2  --request "PATCH"`

command,

in my terminal, I get the following error:

`zsh: no matches found: localhost:8080/checkout?=2`

What am I doing wrong? Here is my code:

```
import (
    "net/http"
    "github.com/gin-gonic/gin"
    "errors"
)

type book struct{
    ID  string   `json: "id"`   //upper case makes it an exported field, but when serialising in json convert the field name to lower case
    Title string  `json: "title"`
    Author string  `json: "author"`
    Quantity int    `json: "quantity"`
}

//mock data is this slice of books (will be a database in a real life example)
var books = []book{
                {ID: "1",  Title: "In Search of Lost Time", Author: "Marcel Proust", Quantity: 2},
                {ID: "2",  Title: "The Great Gatsby", Author: "F. Scott Fitzgerald", Quantity: 5},
                {ID: "3",  Title: "War And Peace", Author: "Leo Tolstoy", Quantity: 6},
}





//set up router to handle main end points of api by implementing the book handling functions first:


//getting all the books
func getBooks(c*gin.Context){
        c.IndentedJSON(http.StatusOK, books)   //nicely indented json, the status that we are sending is status okay, the data that we are sending is "books". So we return a json obejct that has all of the books in it
}


//returning a specic book
func bookById(c *gin.Context) {
    id := c.Param("id")
    book, err := getBookById(id)

    if err != nil {
        c.IndentedJSON(http.StatusNotFound, gin.H{"message": "Book not found."}) //return custom request for bad request or book not found
        return
    }
    c.IndentedJSON(http.StatusOK, book)
}


//getting a book by id
func getBookById(id string) (*book, error) {
    for i, b := range books {
        if b.ID == id {
            return &books[i], nil
        }
    }
    return nil, errors.New("book not found")
}

//* symbol is used to declare a pointer and to dereference, as well as changing the value of the pointer location as well  & symbol points to the address of the stored value.

//checking out a specific book
func checkoutBook(c *gin.Context){
    id, ok := c.GetQuery("id") //chech query parameter in the path built in function in gin framework

    if !ok{
        c.IndentedJSON(http.StatusBadRequest, gin.H{"message": "missing id query parameter"})
        return
    }

    book, err := getBookById(id)

    if err != nil{
        c.IndentedJSON(http.StatusNotFound, gin.H{"message": "Book not found."}) //return custom request for bad request or book not found
        return
    }

    if book.Quantity <= 0{
        c.IndentedJSON(http.StatusBadRequest, gin.H{"message": "Book not available."}) //return custom request for bad request or book not found
        return
    }

    book.Quantity -= 1
    c.IndentedJSON(http.StatusOK, book)

}


func returnBook(c *gin.Context){

    id, ok := c.GetQuery("id") //check query parameter in the path built in function in gin framework

    if !ok{
        c.IndentedJSON(http.StatusBadRequest, gin.H{"message": "missing id query parameter"})
        return
    }

    book, err := getBookById(id)

    if err != nil {
        c.IndentedJSON(http.StatusNotFound, gin.H{"message": "Book not found."})
        return
    }

    book.Quantity += 1
    c.IndentedJSON(http.StatusOK, book)

}




//creating a new book
func createBook(c*gin.Context){ //c stores query parameters, headers

    var newBook book    // the new book is of type book

    if err := c.BindJSON(&newBook); err != nil{

            // if the error is not equal to null, in that case we shall simpy return
            return
        }

    books = append(books, newBook)
    c.IndentedJSON(http.StatusCreated, newBook)
}





func main(){

    //create a gin router
    //can route a specific route to a function with router variable
    router := gin.Default()


    //return all books
    router.GET("/books", getBooks)   //when visting the /books endpoint the getbooks function is called


    //return a specific book
    router.GET("/books/:id", bookById)


    //create a book:
    router.POST("/books", createBook)


    //checkout a book
    router.PATCH("/checkout", checkoutBook)

    //returning in a book
    router.PATCH("/return", returnBook)


    //run the api on a  specific IP (in this case local host) and port (we have chose port 8080)
    router.Run("localhost:8080")

}
```

Comment: `curl -X PATCH 'localhost:8080/return?id=2'` (notice the quotes around the url).

Answer (score 0):

you curl request url is wrong it should be like this

```
curl --location --request PATCH 'localhost:8080/return?id=2'
```